# how to replay sound in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I am trying to replay this sound in my game...but for some reason it's working can somebody please explain me why?

```
   var morning:Sound =new alarmclock ();
                       var transforming:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.5);
                       var morningChannel:SoundChannel = morning.play(0,0,transforming);
                       morningChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, replay);
                       function replay (event:Event) {
                    morningChannel = morning.play(0,0,transforming);    
                    trace ("ANYBODY IN THERE????");
                    }
```

Comment: you need to show all of your code.  what's `pausing`?

Comment: what's `alarmclock()`?

Comment: Please show that class also.  Additionally, you should conform to AS3 conventions by naming your classes in capital-case.  IE:  Instead of `alarmclock()` it should be `Alarmclock()`.

Comment: i am doing it in flash so the class name is inside the library I am just accessing it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
function replay (event:Event) {
  morningChannel = morning.play(0,0,transforming);    
  trace ("ANYBODY IN THERE????");
  morningChannel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, replay );
}
```

> [Note we've added the event listener to the sound channel again. This
>   is because the line "morningChannel = morning.play(0,0,transforming);"
>   causes all event listeners on Sound Channel to be lost.]

I have borrowed the explanation from http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/03/03/avoider-game-tutorial-9/

Answer (score 1):

try this :

import flash.media.Sound;

import flash.media.SoundChannel;

import flash.events.Event;

var demoSound:Sound;

var demoSoundChannel:SoundChannel;

playSound();

function playSound():void
{

```
demoSound = new soundObj();// soundObj is your sound.
demoSoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
demoSoundChannel = demoSound.play();
demoSoundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);
```

}

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{

```
playSound();
```

}

Just a simple example of loop playing, and it is working.
you can add your parameters in play method, it will not impact in looping.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function replay (event:Event)
{
    morningChannel = morning.play(pausing,1,transforming);               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try listening for `Event.COMPLETE` that gets dispatched by the `Sound` object. I've successfully used that in the past to replay a sound.

I didn't know that the `SoundChannel` dispatches it's own `Event.SOUND_COMPLETE` event. Both your code (and the similar code from @Lee Burrows) seems like it should work.

In any case, listening for `Event.COMPLETE` on the `Sound` object might be worth trying:

```
var morningChannel:SoundChannel = morning.play(pausing,1,transforming);
morning.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, replay);

function replay (event:Event)
{
    morningChannel = morning.play(pausing,1,transforming);               
}
```

If this doesn't work either, it could be possible that something is getting garbage collected.

Also, you are passing in `1` to the `play()` method so it loops once. Is that working? Perhaps that is somehow confusing things. You might try setting that to 0, since you are replaying the sound anyway.

Finally, if it's still not working you should set a breakpoint in the `replay()` method (or add a `trace()` statement in it) so you can determine if the event is getting dispatched or not.

Comment: it doesn't work with complete event all together... with my code it looped once but then it just stopped... I tried putting in a trace.. it only gets dispatched once..

Comment: I also got rid of pausing just to see if it changes but for some reason it only likes looping once